How to Automatically Add Strings to the Xcode String Catalog?
When I use Text("Lorem") in SwiftUI, it adds a Lorem key to the Xcode String Catalog (Localizable.xcstrings) at build time. I want to achieve the same behavior for strings that are defined outside of views.
Here’s what I’ve tried:

LocalizedStringKey(“Lorem ipsum”)
String(localized: “Lorem ipsum”)

Both approaches work, but only if I manually add the keys to the String Catalog. This is not ideal because if I forget to add a key, it might go unnoticed.
An alternative could be to use Text() throughout my code and pass it around, but I’d prefer to avoid coupling my presentation layer with the rest of my app. I want to pass a String (or a similar type) to my SwiftUI views and then render it using Text(). This way, I can ensure that no modifiers or unintended changes are applied before the string reaches the UI.
What is the best practice for ensuring that strings used throughout the app are automatically added to the String Catalog at build time without relying on Text() for string management?
I'm targeting iOS 15+.

I cannot reproduce. Localisation keys are automatically added to the string catalog if I write LocalizedStringKey(“Lorem ipsum”). Try this in a new project. You might have configured your project incorrectly.

Just in case you didn't do this, you need to build the project before the string catalog is updated with the new strings.

Interesting, thanks for the response. You are right, it does indeed work in a new project. However, the keys are not being added in the project I'm working on.
Not even in a simple struct like this: import SwiftUI struct TestView: View {let label = LocalizedStringKey("foo bar") /* this key is not added */ var body: some View {Text(label)}}
Do you have any idea what might be the issue?

Check the "Use Compiler to Extract Swift Strings" and "Localized String SwiftUI Support" build settings.

Well, there you go. I've set that before, but apparently did not commit it. Thank you Sweeper, you've helped me!

Based on the fact that Text("...") generates a localisation key but LocalizedStringKey("...") doesn't, it seems like the build setting "Localized String SwiftUI Support" is turned on, but "Use Compiler to Extract Swift Strings" is not turned on.
You should turn on the latter too:

In addition to the forms you suggested, you can also do:
let someText: LocalizedStringKey = "..."

which I think is more idiomatic than LocalizedStringKey("...")
Other types such as LocalizedStringResource also works with this.
